# Comapring the rows of same dataframe

Tags: mysql, r

```
A  B  C
1  2  3
4  2  3
1  2  3
```

I want to compare row1 with row2 and row2 with row3 so on rown with row1.
If they are same I want to print it is as "same" or else "different" in another data frame

output for above table:

```
A            B         C
Different    same      same
Different    same      same
same         same      same
```

For the below code I'm getting

True or false as the output. I want to replace that with Different and same.

```
compare = t(combn(nrow(Data.matrix),2,FUN=function(x)we2009[x[1],]==Data.matrix[x[2],]))
rownames(compare) = combn(nrow(Data.matrix),2,FUN=function(x)paste0("seq",x[1],"_seq",x[2]))
View(compare)
```

Comment: So you want to compare all rows with all rows or just the actual row with the previous one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this deliver the desired results?

```
data_test = data.frame(A = c(1,4,1), B = c(2,2,2), C = c(3,3,3)) 

# create shifted helper-columns 
data_test_help = cbind(data_test, data_test[c(2:NROW(data_test), 1),])
# apply comparision on each row
t(apply(data_test_help,1, function(f) f[1:3] == f[4:6]))
# for same, different notation instead of true false
t(apply(data_test_help,1, function(f)  ifelse(f[1:3] == f[4:6], "same", "Different")))
```

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of options how to do that ,

since you add MySQL tag the easiest way is to do that with sql in case you have limited number of  columns , you can also use package SQL in r

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('select 
    case when a=b then 'same' else 'different' as a
    case when b=c then 'same' else 'different' as b
    case when c=a then 'same' else 'different' as c
    from my_dataset'
```